# Are these walls load bearing?

Tags: walls, structural, removal, load-bearing

[image]Looking purchase this house, however, want to remove the bar and closets in "red", could that whole area be removed, or are those load-bearing/structural walls? The original structure for this house was a single story and these current plans are the proposed extension, upwards. Any help will be really appreciated. [image: Floor plan:]

Comment: They could be. Do you have the structural plans as well? That's what I need to be able to tell.

Comment: Hi represton, 
The real estate agent doesn't have the structural plans, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the walls around the bar and closet do not appear to be load bearing walls, except I would not remove the North-South wall between the Kitchen and Lounge.

The dashed lines on the Ground Floor Plan indicate the structural floor framing for the the First Floor Plan (above).

As you can see, a steel beam has been added just South of the Bar area and extends over the Kitchen. However, none of the new floor joists rests on the walls around the Bar, except the North-South between the Kitchen and Lounge.

Comment: Thanks @lee-sam, that is very helpful, so if I am able to remove the walls, in "green" on the updated picture, that will work?

Comment: Yes, you can remove the walls marked in green. To check my answer, look in the attic and you’ll see no beams, joists, posts, etc. resting on these walls.